# A different tank for the commode

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I purchased a 1.6 commode that was made after the year 2000. The tank busted. I have another tank I found at a salvage store. Actually the whole commode. I removed the tank and wanted to put it on this one.. Will this work? I put it on the bowel and it leaked but I think it was just the seal. It was old. If I replace the seal with this fix the leak..Every thing seemed to line up ok...

Comment: I know you can order these at Lowes but it takes about 10 days. I run a business and dont have the time to wait..I really need to get this fixed asap.. If you have answer please let me know.. The salvage tank looks to be of regular size Please send email.. thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: if it fits and the holes line up, what else can go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The tank to stool interface for most units is pretty much the same. So if it looks like the two holes used to secure the tank to the stool match up and the center water passage hole under the flapper valve is in the same location you should be good to go (at least in the USA).

Re-using old seals can be a problem and lead to leaks. When you mount up the salvaged tank you should replace the bolt seals and the seal that sits between the tank and the stool.

The reason the seals need replacing is that they harden with age, lose compliance and can even sometimes crack. Part of this relates to the chlorine in the water. The tank to tub seal also can take on a compressed shape and if the salvage tank is not exactly the same form and fit in the seal area you can have a leak problem.

I would recommend getting a tank mounting kit that includes the seals and new tank attach bolts and throw the old parts away. Probably also a good idea to replace the flapper valve at the same time.

Comment: Excelent answer I can't add anything or doubt others could.+